# Appimage on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: appimage

I cannot run any AppImage on Ubuntu 22.04.

Of course, I went to the propriety and put the flag on "Run as executable" but once I double-click on it nothing happen. I tried 3 AppImages but nothing happen.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Check file permissions in the terminal to see if executable bit is set. Try running from the command line: errors may be displayed in the terminal that hint to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that i needed to install libfuse2 to make them work

Comment: OK, then you may not have a default install - probably an upgrade

Answer (score 25):

Ubuntu 22.04 will no longer ship with the `libfuse2` package by default. The AppImage distribution (and more generally, all existing AppImage's) are built expecting `libfuse2` support. This means that AppImage's will not run on Ubuntu 22.04 by default.

The user would have to manually run:

```
sudo apt install libfuse2*
```

prior to executing any AppImage.

**Reference**: [I get some errors related to something called “FUSE” — AppImage documentation](https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/troubleshooting/fuse.html#setting-up-fuse-2-x-alongside-of-fuse-3-x-on-recent-ubuntu-22-04-debian-and-their-derivatives).

Comment: There must be something else because libfuse2 does not help.

Comment: As a SO fan boy, I run this command. Or more like installed the fuse2 and libfuse which meant that fuse3 was removed among other gnome packages on my Ubuntu 22.10. Only to find out it broke the Gnome desktop interface preventing any boot. So be INFORMED.

Answer (score 2):

So I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 (where `.appimage` was working fine) to 22.04 (where .appimage isn't running anymore) when I double-click on icon it won't open when I run it using the terminal `./<.appimage name>` it gives me this error

> [359794:1206/185235.385867:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(1034)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye.
> Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

even after I downloaded `libfuse2` and made sure it was executable. I'm not sure why this works or if there's maybe something wrong with this method, but it worked for me.

You can navigate to your directory where the app is installed, open the terminal and type this `./<your .appimage name> --no-sandbox` and that's it.
Again I'm not really sure why this would work, but it does at least for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1267134)

Comment: The '--no-sandbox' flag worked for me.

Comment: Those apps [were electron-based](https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/troubleshooting/electron-sandboxing.html#allow-electron-appimages-to-run-without-unprivileged-namespaces)?

Answer (score 2):

AppImages require [FUSE](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE) version 2 to run.
Many distributions have a working FUSE setup out-of-the-box. However if it is not working for you, you may need to install and configure FUSE manually.

For example, on Ubuntu (>= 22.04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Warning: While `libfuse2` is OK, do not install the `fuse` package as of 22.04 or you may break your system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).