# AppImages won't open on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: appimage

First of all, I have given it permissions to execute.

I have installed `libfuse2`.

Still won't open. I should mention that I have another machine with Ubuntu 22.04 where they open fine. Not sure how should I debug this and what further info to provide.

**UPDATE:**

The only difference I can think off on the device that AppImages don't work is that I have flatpak installed and more programs installed. I've tried 2 AppImmages, Ray and balenaEtcher. I've tried one other AppImage actually, don't remember which one, I downloaded one randomly just to test it out, that didn't work either.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is what I've found in kern.log:

```
Apr 25 12:20:23 amir-B560M-DS3H-V2 kernel: [  297.016063] traps: Chrome_IOThread[12739] trap int3 ip:55a9a97afcd8 sp:7f003d511320 error:0 in balena-etcher-electron.bin[55a9a9584000+6271000]
```

Comment: Start by telling us the software you are trying to run and the exact details of what you tried so far. It's best if you describe the problem as it manifests without making assumptions and using those assumptions to make a statement that may not be true-- For example, the theory you pose in your question can't be true if you have another installation of the same OS where the problem doesn't exist. Perhaps describe to us what is different on this device, since that may lead to a solution.

Comment: @Nmath The only difference I can think off on the device that AppImages don't work is that I have flatpak installed and more programs installed. I've tried 2 AppImmages, [Ray](https://myray.app/) and [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). I've tried one other AppImage actually, don't remember which one, I downloaded one randomly just to test it out, that didn't work either.

Comment: Please add any info relevant to diagnose the problem directly to your question: use "edit". Comments are there to help to improve questions and answers, not to contain additional info. Few people will read through all the comments to find the info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403811/appimage-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: @AmirRami I believe that balenaEtcher is built using Chromium, so you may try using the Chromium flag: --no-sandbox For example: ./etcher.AppImage --no-sandbox

Comment: @UriHerrera Yeah, did that already, long time ago, worked fine with it.